# Linking to shared object with a version number (libexample.so.1) and the gcc "-l:" option

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I am having trouble dynamically linking my program to OpenAL on gnu/linux.

The command `sudo ldconfig -p | grep openal` prints:

> libopenal.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1

The command I initially used to link was `gcc test.o -lopenal` but that didn't work. The error message I get is:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenal

After searching the web a long time I found a solution that works (note the colon after -l):

> gcc test.o -l:libopenal.so.1

The solution works but I cannot seem to find any documentation on the special link option used.

My question is what the best way to link to a shared object with a version suffix (like `libopenal.so.1`) is.
It would also be good to know what the `-l:libname.so` option does, so if someone can explain it and/or point me to some documentation about it I would be very glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not link to the specific version number.  Instead, you should link against a plain `libopenal.so` which would be a symlink to `libopenal.so.1`.  If this symlink does not exist, it means you are probably missing the "openal-devel" or "openal-dev" package from your Linux distro's package manager.  Install that and you should have a symlink, and can then build with the normal `-lopenal` syntax.

For more details, see here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=163268

Comment: by the way, if you don't have the libopenal.so link, you probably don't have also the proper header files to compile.  Normally they get created when you install the development package, but you can create them, or even you can link with the full path to the library, as for example `gcc text.o /usr/lib/libopenal.so.1`, in case you don't have enough privileges to make the link yourself.

Answer (score -1):

you are right you may install dev package. But question was another. Above the way to link so lib in case there is no symlink to original lib so file without version. I don't sure is all in any similar case. Certainly you may create manually symlink without version to original so(not to openal.so.1 because it i also link. So it will work too. But never do so... link to link it is bad idea) and normal syntax will be work. But if you need headers files you must install dev rpm. There is no reason to link so lib with version without headers. Or you can't use exported functions from this lib. If you don't author of this lib...